# "Thank you back" VS "Thank you as well" VS "Thank to you, also"

Tags: grammar, phrases

1. "Thank to you, too."
2. "Thank to you, also."
3. "Thanks to you, too."
4. "Thanks to you, also."
5. "Thank you, too."
6. "Thank you, also."
7. "Thank you as well."
8. "Thank you to you too."
9. "Thank you back."
10. "I also thank you."
11. "I thank you, too"
12. "You're also thank you."
13. "You're thank you, too."
14. "You're welcome."

Which ones of these are really used?

Answer (score 1):

1, 2, 8, 9, 12, 13 are just incorrect.
10 is not idiomatic but not grammatically incorrect.

The rest would be more a matter of style and situation. I'd also say the 'also' variants are less common than the 'too' variants.
Of course, when you don't have to thank the other because you just helped them without getting anything back, "you're welcome" would be the more appropriate one.